# Can we create custom sdk's on our own

Tags: iphone, sdk

I want to create the custom sdk like adMob on my  own. But i have no idea, I want to know is there any example or guidance available, as i have not found any such material over net. I asked same earlier also, but not got expected answers, that's why trying to ask again in more efficient manner.
I want to build a sdk that can be downloaded by the user, added to the app and be usable.

Please guide for the above.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Both of the links submitted in the original answer have expired since 2011

Those still interested in the topic please consider one of the following:

[Xcode 6 and Embedded Frameworks only supported in iOS8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909870/xcode-6-and-embedded-frameworks-only-supported-in-ios8)

[Embedded Frameworks < iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29682272/embedded-frameworks-ios-8)

https://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios

---

<strike>Maybe some of these links will be helpful:</strike>

http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/04/07/creating-static-libraries-for-ios/

http://db-in.com/blog/2011/07/universal-framework-iphone-ios-2-0/

Comment: Links are inactive(Expired)

Comment: @Loganathan thanks! I've added the answer a long time ago when these links were working. I've added some other reference instead of the broken ones. They're not very concrete, but the question is broad enough to be answered simply or concisely.