# Embedded Frameworks < iOS 8

Tags: ios, frameworks

Ok, so [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27637992/1951992) had **no problems** building **and submitting** an App, targeting iOS 7+, using an Embedded framework.

He points out that an [Apple Engineer nick-named 'SevenTenEleven'](https://devforums.apple.com/message/999579#999579) mentioned in the Apple Dev Forums that the following warning...

## ld: warning: embedded dylibs/frameworks only run on iOS 8 or later

...is just a bug.

The warning is still present in Xcode 6.3 and it seems that an App store submission is the only way to know for myself, if this is actually a bug or not.

Has anyone found any documentation that suggests this is just a bug and that there is in fact, nothing to worry about ?

Building an App just to see if a framework like this can target iOS 7, and make it through the App Store submission process, is crazy.  Unfortunately, my client just wants an SDK, so there is no App I can do a test run on at the moment.

Comment: 'Loretoparisi' mentioned here https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/1480.  "At WWDC they pointed out that You can build CocoaTouch Frameworks on iOS8 only; You can run them on lower iOS versions as well; On XCode6 GM is not working, now trying XCode 6.0.1 (supposed not be exactly the same binarie of XCode 6 GM). This seems to be a Apple Mach-O Linker warnings that should be ignored."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Used a ticket to speak with Apple

"Hi Rob,

Thank you for contacting Apple Developer Technical Support (DTS). I am currently investigating your issue. To answer your question, I need to consult with some folks in iTunes Connect. Unfortunately this can take some time as they are very busy.

In the meantime, I will point out that it is only supported to use an embedded framework on iOS 8. The only question is whether you could use dlopen() to conditionally load the embedded framework on iOS 8, and not load the embedded framework on earlier versions of iOS.

I will let you know what I hear from iTunes Connect about this question.

Luke Rattei
 DTS Engineer"

"Hi Rob,

Embedded frameworks are only supported on iOS 8 and above. Unfortunately you will not be able to use an embedded framework on iOS 7.

While it might be possible to run apps with embedded frameworks on iOS 7 during development, you will not be able to submit such apps to the App Store. You will see an error message that the MinimumOSVersion of your embedded framework must be at least 8.0.

Luke Rattei
 DTS Engineer"

Comment: OMG ! what a bad news ! Did you find a way to solve your problem ? any solution ? tip .. ?

Answer (score 1):

> While it might be possible to run apps with embedded frameworks on iOS 7 during development, you will not be able to submit such apps to the App Store. You will see an error message that the MinimumOSVersion of your embedded framework must be at least 8.0.

I encountered this exact problem about a month ago. I was forced to target iOS 8.0 in my app and embedded frameworks projects.

And I just tried to submit the app again with the iOS 7 support, and this time it has been approved!

I'm crazy? To be honest I have trouble understanding the logic around this.

Alex.

Comment: I've just tried the "Validate" option on my archive targeting iOS 7.1 which included an embedded framework and it's passed successfully as well. Haven't tried a deployment, but I don't see why it would be rejected only after uploading.

Comment: Same problem here, no issue Archiving, but fails during upload to itunesconnect (using App Loader).